# How to stretch matplot plot in cell in pdf report?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, reportlab

Using reportlab I creating pdf report, and there is a table, consist of 1 cell, in which a plot, created using matplot and seaborn.

```
self.flat_data = [self.table_N[i][j] for i in range(5) for j in range(1,6)]
sns.displot(self.flat_data, kind="kde", bw_adjust=1.0)
plt.axvline(self.LotM_N, color='g', label='Значення лоту')
plt.axvline(self.gm_N, color='r', label='Середнє')
plt.axvline(self.vib_N, color='gold', label='Межі зміщення')
plt.axvline(self.vitop_N, color='gold', label='Межі зміщення')
plt.title("Оцінка розподілу")
plt.xlabel("Розподіл")
plt.ylabel("Значення")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('foo.png', dpi=600)
im2 = Image('foo.png', width=56*mm, height=56*mm)
table13 = Table([[im2]], colWidths=115*mm, rowHeights=56*mm)
table13.setStyle([("VALIGN", (0,0), (-1,-1), "MIDDLE"),
                ("ALIGN", (0,0), (-1,-1), "CENTER"),
                ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, black),
                ('LINEABOVE', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, black),
                ('LINEBELOW', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, black),
                ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, black)])
table13.wrapOn(c, width, height)
table13.drawOn(c, 170*mm, 18*mm)
os.remove('foo.png')
```

Where `self.table_N` is 2d array of float numbers; `self.LotM_N`, `self.gm_N`, `self.vib_N`, `self.vitop_N` are float variables.
It works as I want, but plot not fill entire cell. If I change `im2 = Image('foo.png', width=56*mm, height=56*mm)` width here, it will strech image, not plot itself. arrows show where it should be stretched https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oaOE.png

How to make that plot will take the entire width of the cell?